# making snakefile for data analysis

Tags: snakemake

I am making a `Snakefile` for data analysis. the extension of my raw data is .RCC. for example the first input file I have is: CF30207_01.RCC.
and the script I am running on the data is `QC.py`. Looking at the tutorial, I have made the following snakefile:

```
SAMPLES = ["CF30207_01",
           "CF30212_06",
           "CF30209_03",
           "CF30213_07",
           "CF30211_05",
           "CF30214_08"]

rule all:
    input:
        expand('{sample}.RCC', sample=SAMPLES)


rule QC:
        input:
            rc = '/home/snakemaker/{sample}.RCC'

        output:
                '{sample}.pdf'
                "quality_control.csv"

        shell:
                "python3 QC.py"
```

but I got the following errors:

```
./Snakefile: line 1: SAMPLES: command not found
./Snakefile: line 2: CF30212_06,: command not found
./Snakefile: line 3: CF30209_03,: command not found
./Snakefile: line 4: CF30213_07,: command not found
./Snakefile: line 5: CF30211_05,: command not found
./Snakefile: line 6: CF30214_08]: command not found
./Snakefile: line 8: rule: command not found
./Snakefile: line 9: input:: command not found
./Snakefile: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `'{sample}.RCC','
./Snakefile: line 10: `        expand('{sample}.RCC', sample=SAMPLES)'
```

but I followed exactly the same structures. do you guys know how I can fix the problem is with this snakefile?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are executing the snakefile script itself as `./Snakefile`. Instead, you should do

```
snakemake -s /path/to/Snakefile
```

Or just `snakemake` if the Snakefile is in the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to snakemake!  You have a good start, but couple of other notes on your snakefile.

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand('{sample}.RCC', sample=SAMPLES)
```

The rule all should request the final *outputs* of your workflow, not the inputs.  These are the files you are requesting to be made.  Change the input to:

```
        expand('{sample}.pdf', sample=SAMPLES)
```

For the QC rule, it doesn't seem like you are passing the input/output files to the QC.py script.  If you have command line arguments in that function, you can add them like:

```
   "python3 QC.py --input {input.rc} --output {output[0]}"
```

Alternatively you can pass QC.py to the [script directive](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#external-scripts) and use `snakemake.input[0]`, etc to access the files in your python code.

Within the output

```
output:
    '{sample}.pdf'
    "quality_control.csv"
```

You need to add a comma between the files to make them a list.  Also note that every sample will output to the same `quality_control.csv`.  At best this will overwrite and only keep the last sample, if you have multithreading you may have an error in your python code.  You may want something like:

```
output:
    '{sample}.pdf',
    'quality_control_{sample}.csv'
```

If your QC code actually appends to quality_control, you can instead force a single execution at a time for that rule with [custom resources](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#resources)

A good test for new snakefiles is to run `snakemake -nq` to make sure the file syntax is ok and you have the expected number of rules queued up.